# What is wrong with my matrix multiplication method?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, matrix

I'm writing a matrix multiplication method using java. My class is `Table` which is a 2D array. This is the constructor of `Table`:

```
public Table(int n, int m, int val)
    {
        assert(n > 0 && m > 0);
        elements = new int[n][m];

        for(int row = 0; row < elements.length; row++)
        {
            for(int col = 0; col < elements[row].length; col++)
            {
                elements[row][col] = val;
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is the method I'm talking about:

```
public static Table product(Table a, Table b)
    {
        assert(a.numCols() == b.numRows()) : "different dimensions!" + null;
        Table c = new Table(a.numRows(), b.numCols(),0);
        int res = 0;

        for(int row = 0; row < a.numRows(); row++)
        {
            for(int col = 0; col < b.numCols(); col++)
            {
                for(int k = 0; k < a.numCols(); k ++)
                {
                    res = res + a.get(row, k) * b.get(k, col);
                    c.set(row, col, res);
                }
            }

        }
        System.out.println(c.toString());
        return c;

    }
```

The method product should return a new `Table` which is the result of the multiplication of a and b. I think it's pretty clear what it should do. The problem is that it only computes `c[0][0]` correctly; So `c.get(0,0)` is computed correctly, but the results after that are not. Do you see what I'm doing wrong? I appreciate your help.

Comment: What is the result of c.get(1,1)?

Comment: This is unrelated to your problem, but you are misusing assert.  asserts should be used for events you believe are impossible, eg. `if (x<0) { doThis(); } else if ( x >0 ) { doThat(); } else if ( x==0 ) { theOtherThing();} else { assert false ; }`  If my logic is correct the assertion should never happen and if the assertion happens that indicates my logic is flawed.  The situation that the number of columns does not match the number of rows is better handled with some type of Exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing that looks odd is:

```
int res = 0;
```

it should be reset in other place too. Hope that helps :)

```
...
        for(int col = 0; col < b.numCols(); col++)
        {
            res = 0;
            for(int k = 0; k < a.numCols(); k ++)
....
```

Answer (score 1):

`res` is only set to zero all the way outside the whole set of loops. Its value doesn't make a lot of sense in your multiplication core routine. Re-check your loop logic.

Answer (score 1):

Reset res in the first loop (might need some re-ordering of the loops, havn't checked and matrices is to long ago) or just change

```
res = res + a.get(row, k) * b.get(k, col);
```

to

```
res = c.get(row, col) + a.get(row, k) * b.get(k, col);
```

Answer (score 1):

`int res = 0;` should be between the second and the third for-loops.